# Remove record from Database in Linq

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

My picture is :
[image: Picture]

I want to remove record from `Tbl_Category` table.

`Tbl_category` have childs and its child has child and .... to `Tbl_File`

How I can remove `Tbl_Category` records ?

Thank you

In Tbl_user , "username" is Primary key and the session username is :

```
string u = Session["Username"].ToString();
```

could you please help me to write the query ?

Comment: which ORM you are usiing? Entity Framework?

Comment: You really need to show what you tried yourself because it's unclear which approach you're aiming at to begin with. There are many ways to delete records from the database.

Comment: MR Hazarath Chillara . Yes  Entity Framework

Comment: MR Gert Arnold I show it in picture . I want to remove a row in tbl_category buy it has 3 table child . at first i should remove table child and after that remove row in tbl_category .

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to delete category from category table object. `categoryID` is the id you want to delete from table

```
Tbl_Category category= dbContext.Tbl_Category.Single(x => x.CategoryID== categoryID);    
    if(category!=null)
    { 
       dbContext.Tbl_Category.Remove(standard1);
       dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Also check the  `WillCascadeOnDelete() method` on context is turned ON or OFF

Comment: Hello . I want to delete tbl_File row . i show it in picture

Comment: replace Tbl_Cateogry  in above with Tbl_File and category id with file id

Comment: it should check and remove a row that just is created by that "Username" . No one can remove other row.